# JavaScript перенос данных между activeListBox yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Есть 2 таблицы activeListBox. В одной есть данные, во второй нет. Как мне сделать перенос выбранных данных из одной таблицы в другую по нажатию на соответствующую клавишу?

**Код view:**

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active panel panel-primary" id="questionintopik">
   <div class="row">

      <!-- Таблица №1 -->

      <div class="col-lg-5">
         <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
            <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
            <input id="search-avaliable">
            <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
            <?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $LeftItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
         <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
      </div>

      <!-- Кнопки -->

      <div class="col-lg-1">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <script type="text/javascript">

         function PastToRight()
         {
            alert("Add to right!");
         }

         function PastToLeft()
         {
            alert("Add to left!");
         }
      </script>

      <a id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success" onclick="PastToRight()" >&gt;&gt;</a><br>
      <a id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="PastToLeft()">&lt;&lt;</a>

      </div>

      <!-- Таблица №2 -->

      <div class="col-lg-5">
         <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
            <h4>Вопросы входящие в эту тему</h4>
            <input id="search-assigned"><br>
            <?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $RightItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
         <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Вот как это выглядит:**
[image: фото]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот набросал рабочий пример, дадите селекторы только своих селектов и замените в js:

```js
        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#btn-add', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selected = $(document).find('#first option:selected');
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selected.appendTo('#second');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#btn-remove', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selected = $(document).find('#second option:selected');
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selected.appendTo('#first');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
    <select name="first" id="first" size="5" style="width: 100px;" multiple>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
<br>
      <a id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success"  >&gt;&gt;</a>
      <br>
      <a id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger">&lt;&lt;</a>
<br>
    <select name="second" id="second" size="5" style="width: 100px;" multiple>
    </select>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Для js надо отдельный файл создавать? Или можно прямо там где у меня вставить код?

`<script type="text/javascript">
СЮДА
</script>`

Comment: Да можно внизу под прописанием jquery код этот написать

Comment: В смысле под прописанием jquery ? не понял =(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4e63pjqz/ вот так

Comment: Так, добавил ту строчку с googleapis jquery, после чего вставил <script type="text/javascript">  $(function() { ...ТУТ ВАШ КОД ...}); </script>, посмотрел на странице вывода название селектора, у меня и в первой и во второй таблице селектор называется "squiztopic-id_rec", поменял названия на него и ничего не происходит

Comment: селекторы не верные, мой пример работает, что-то у себя смотрите

Comment: Ну вот у меня данные выводятся этой строчкой 
<?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $LeftItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
Тут нету ни названий селекторов, ничего. Но когда смотрю код страницы, то там уже выводится название селектора как "squiztopic-id_rec".

Comment: судя по коду 2 селетора с одинаковым ID, в опции после 'style' => 'width: 100%' добавьте 'id' => 'first' а на второй  'id' => 'second' к примеру, а из-за того что и там и там селектор тот же ничего и не работает

Comment: отлично, спасибо, все зараобтало)

Answer (score 1):

Так хотите?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080087/how-to-transfer-listbox-value-to-another-listbox-using-jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/fLAy6/1/

```
$("#moveright").click(function(){
   $("#country > option:selected").each(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#planets");
   });
});
```